# How to get data stored for an authenticated user store in a table in a database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve data using this code in my controller to create a foreach table in my blade.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use illuminate\Http\Resquest;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\user;
use DB;
use Auth;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HistoryController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function show($user)
    {
        
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        $history = DB::table('funds')->where('user_id', $user_id);

        return view('history.index')->with('funds',$history);
    }
}
```

I need to understand the concept of using database query builder in fetching data.

Comment: you have to execute the query, add `->get()` to the statement assigned to `$history` https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#retrieving-results

Comment: it display data when i use the dd() but display this error: Trying to get property 'bankname' of non-object (View: C:\Users\user pc\Desktop\dkn\resources\views\history\index.blade.php).in my blage file when i use the code ```{{$history ?? ''->bankname}}```

Comment: because `''` is not an object and the variable isn't named `history` you have passed it to the view as `funds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `get()`**

```
    public function show($user)
    {

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        $history = DB::table('funds')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();


        return view('history.index')->with('funds',$history);

    }
```

**or**

```
return view("history.index", compact("history "));
```

**or**

```
$history = DB::table('funds')->select('bankname')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

**Blade.php**

```
@foreach($history as $item)
{
    <p>{{$item->bankname}}</p>
    <p>{{$item->updated_at}}</p>
}
```

Comment: thanks it's giving me a json file but i just want to select a single column

Comment: which coloumn you want to get?\

Comment: You can use chaining with the query builder ->select('columnName') before get(). also you should read the laravel documentation, that will be useful for you.

Comment: $history = DB::table('funds')->select('bankname')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

Comment: can you get your answer.?/

Comment: please i want to select the last created row in the funds table for the authenticated user

Comment: I'm getting this error:Property [bankname] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\Users\user pc\Desktop\dkn\resources\views\funds\show.blade.php)

Comment: when i use the code: $summary = DB::table('funds')->select('bankname')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get() in my controller

Comment: return view("history.index", compact("summary "));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204031/discussion-between-toby-nwude-and-vikas-katariya).

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
public function show($user)
{

    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    $history = DB::table('funds')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

    return view('history.index', compact('history'));
}
```

In your blade just use the variable `$history` in foreach.

**Blade**

```
@foreach($history as $item)
{
    <p>{{$item->bankname}}</p>
    <p>{{$item->updated_at}}</p>
}
```

Comment: thanks but i also want to display the last updated row of the user

Comment: You can just remove the select chain method in order to get the all columns but only display the data needed. `$history = DB::table('funds')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();`